# Dynamically suspend execution of user-submitted Javascript code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, yield, event-loop

I am developing a game that dynamically executes user-submitted Javascript code in a sandbox environment.

A user script might look something like this:

```js
function main() {
  console.log("before foo");
  foo();
  console.log("after foo");
}
```

`foo` is a function that I expose to the user that executes some action within the game. The action takes a few seconds to complete.

**I would like to suspend execution of the user's script until the action is complete- without blocking the game engine.**

This is a trivial task if I was the author of the code- I could simply use `await` or `yield`. But I would rather not impose that requirement on the user, as this would make scripts syntactically clunky. Also, within the logic of the game, it doesn't make sense for `foo` to be asynchronous.

*Essentially, I need to dynamically "yieldify" Javascript code.*

One approach is to parse the script into an AST using a library such as [esprima](https://esprima.org/), dynamically insert `yield`/`await` expressions where needed, and then  re-generate the code so that it looks something like this:

```js
function* main() {
  console.log("before foo");
  yield foo();
  console.log("after foo");
}
```

But is there a simpler solution to this problem? Perhaps there is some Javascript feature or npm library that I am overlooking.

Comment: Honestly the AST way sounds like the best you could think of. It even allows you to sanitize the user's scripts.

Comment: I don't see `async`/`await` as clunky… But if "*within the logic of the game, it doesn't make sense for `foo` to be asynchronous*" then why is it actually asynchronous?

Comment: "*dynamically insert yield/await expressions where needed*" - notice that this will be very limiting on the user. They cannot write generator/async functions themselves any more, and they cannot use `foo` in synchronous callbacks (where you cannot - easily - rewrite them) such as `forEach` or `replace`. If you really want to do such a thing, be very clear in the documentation about how the rewriting works, don't sell it as "magic" as it's bound to fail quite often in very weird ways.

Comment: How exactly does your "sandbox environment" look? It might be possible to use the debugger API to actually **breakpoint** on the `foo` call (stopping the entire sandbox code evaluation) and injecting the return value once your game engine is ready.